# Android Studio: multiple apps with library projects in common

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I've done a bit of reading.  I understand the theory of Eclipse workspaces/projects vs AS projects/modules, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to best reproduce my Eclipse setup, or if it's even what Android Studio wants me to do.

I have two applications. For the sake of illustration, let's call them *EmployeeApp* and *CustomerApp*. These are different applications in every sense - different packages, wildly different source, everything; as far as I can see, they are certainly not just product flavours.

However they both use a lot of library modules, and for the most part, they use the same ones. They also live under the same structure in the same repo.

I wrote separate Gradle scripts for both apps before this migration, and that's what I used to import them. In that way, I can import the top level applications, and end up with two projects in two windows, like this:

[image: Android Studio project view 1]   [image: Android Studio project view 2]

The trouble with this is that if someone changes a library project, they at the very least need to know whether it's broken the two apps that depend on it, so ideally I want them in the same view.

First question then: now that it's 2016, does Android Studio allow me to do that, and is it regarded as an intended usage?

If so: how do I do it? I've tried importing the missing parts of one into the other using the 'Import Module' feature, but it apparently does very little.

Comment: imo - understanding gradle/android library best practice is much more important than eclipse v AS stuff. suggest review on http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules  then if u want to see this kind of mgmt in action go and build or review a lib proj like https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseUI-Login/build.gradle  which is manage at the proj level by https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/build.gradle  .. if you spend the time to understand the implementation of the lib stuff from a well-design lib project may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've resolved this myself. Only time will tell if it's actually an appropriate solution in practice or not.

The problem stemmed from the fact that I'd basically created two independent Gradle scripts, i.e:

```
Android\EmployeeApp\build.gradle
Android\CustomerApp\build.gradle
```

whereas what made this work was a top-level build as well, i.e.:

```
Android\build.gradle
Android\EmployeeApp\build.gradle
Android\CustomerApp\build.gradle
```

This didn't contain much:

```
dependencies {
        project(":EmployeeApp")
        project(":CustomerApp")
}
```

and then `build.settings` simply included one of these pairs for *every* project:

```
include ':Services'
project(':Services').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, './Services')
```

I then imported that top level `build.gradle` and almost all was well.

I did have to do a bit more, like move `repositories` and `allProjects` to the top level, but this will be specific to whatever you have.